# Determine where a class is imported from in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any way to determine where a class is coming from in python (especially sklearn)?  I want to determine if a class is from sklearn.linear_models or sklearn.ensemble.

As an example, I would like to be able to determine if Ridge() is a member of sklearn.linear_model.

The fit function is a bit different depending on the model so formulas fed to each via patsy need to be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `__module__` attribute, i.e.: `Ridge.__module__`

If you want to know it from an instance of the class: `inst.__class__.__module__`

If you need the module object (not just the name as string): `sys.modules[Ridge.__module__]`